# ORA-37409 Cannot drop analytic workspace in AWM

Tags: oracle, olap, oracle-olap

I wanted to delete an Analytics Workspace in AWM,but the action stopped with this error :

**ORA-37409: cannot delete or truncate AW used by CUBE ORGANIZED table**

After I closed AWM and open it again, the list of dimensions and cubes was empty but I could not still delete the AW.

I also tried to delete the table **AW$TMPMyCube** directly from database :
**drop table AW$TMPMyCube purge**
  I got the same error (ORA-37409: ...)

How can I delete AW forcefully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I dropped all **MVs** related to my AW directly from database